# Open one tab at a time _python-webbrowser

Tags: python, url, python-webbrowser

I'm am working on my first attempt writing a program that opens a Wikipedia page based on year entered, but each time I run the program, the tabs open for every year I have listed so far.

I have tried writing it as a *for loop, while loop,* and (attempted and *if statement*); how can I make it so only one tab opens for the correct input year? `

```
year_entered = input("year of interest? ")
year = ''
ninety_five = webbrowser.open_new_tab('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1995/')

#this is repeated for years 1995-2020


#I've also tried *while True:* 

 for year_entered in range(1995, 2000):
   year = str(year_entered)
   if year == "1995":
       print(ninety_five)
       break
   elif year == "1996":
       print(ninety_six)
       break
```

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you kind of messed up the whole workflow of the program, so I will try to guide you through a method of making it.

1. First, you need to get the desired year; simple enough, we just need one variable to do that, that part is okay.
2. Then, we need to actually get the url of the year's wikipedia page. We can accomplish that by adding the beginning of the url, and the year that we just got with the `input` method.
3. Now, all that is left, is to open this site with the `webbrowser` module.

Your code should be looking something like this:

```
import webbrowser
year_entered = input("year of interest? ")  # We store the year entered in a variable
url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/' + year_entered  # We use the above variable to construct a url
webbrowser.open_new_tab(url)  # We then open that url
```

Note, that I haven't used any loops, because we aren't actually looping, or going through something a couple of times. Also, if you have a lot of `if else` statements in your code, most of the times you can do it in a more efficient and less time-consuming way.